# Prevent Subscriber Role to login

Tags: login, user-roles

How can I prevent a Subscriber to login?

I want to prevent the user role.

Comment: The question would why do you allow subscribers to register if you don't want them to be able to log in?

Answer (score 1):

The [authenticate filter hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/authenticate) is used to perform additional validation/authentication any time a user logs in to WordPress.

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'check_login', 100, 3);
function check_login($user, $username, $password) {
      if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
          // Check if user is a subscriber then stop login
          if (in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles) {
               return null;
          }
      }

    return $user;
}
```

I hope this may help.